# Crystal Reports - Details diplaying misaligned in Page Header

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio and I'm having a strange issue that's confounding me.  I have a few simple reports comprised of 3-5 columns of data from a database. On my Production server (IIS 7.5) the Details section displays overlaying the Page Header which are the column headings.  The strange part is it's not all the columns on any given report.  It could be one column or multiple columns but at least one column displays correctly.  In Report Preview, on my Development Machine, or on my Intranet (IIS 6) the reports display perfectly.  I've searched extensively and tried a number of things but I'm at a loss.

The dll versions in the BIN directory match between environments and the files in the aspnet_client match as well.

Comment: can you try increasing the margins of column headers?

Comment: When I do that the data does not overlap but the effected columns print one row higher than where they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out and it's a two parter...

1) The first problem was a version mismatch between GAC's on my development machine and my live server.  My server was running 13,04.705 and my development machine was 13.02.469.  Once, I updated my development machine I could reproduce the behavior on both.

2) To recap the issue...  The details columns would print like this.

Name                                     Info
            Data           Data

The problem turned out to be that formula fields would display a row higher than data fields in their row.

To resolve the issue, I had to change the Paragraph formatting on each object.  The Line Spacing was set to 1.5 for Formula fields when I changed that to 1 everything lined up.